# Why does scaling the features affect the prediction of a regression?

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, svm

I'm working on a regression problem using the support vector regression model from sklearn and using MinMax to scale the features, but by using it I get a different result for the regression, does that makes sense?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import  svm
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

np.random.seed(0)
X_training = np.random.rand(100,15)*10
Y_training = np.random.rand(100,1)*10
model = svm.SVR()
```

without scaling:

```
model.fit(X_training,Y_training)
print model.predict(X_training)[0:10]

array([ 4.99980599,  6.99479293,  4.9784396 ,  5.03911175,  6.99557904,
        6.57214885,  6.99454049,  5.60940831,  6.99989978,  5.98628179])
```

Using MinMax scaler:

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_scaled  = scaler.fit_transform(X_training)
model.fit(X_scaled,Y_training)
model.predict(X_scaled)[0:10]

array([ 5.63521939,  6.70378514,  5.83393228,  5.33274858,  6.47539108,
        5.61135278,  5.7890052 ,  5.74425789,  6.15799404,  6.1980326 ])
```

Although the prediction is in the same order of magnitude there is a significant difference between both cases.

Answer (score 0):

For a normal linear regression, you're correct that scaling the feature values should have no effect. The difference here is that sklearn's default SVM kernel isn't linear.

Based on the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html) for svm.SVR:

- **kernel** parameter: If none is given, ‘[rbf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_kernel)’ will be used.
- **gamma** parameter: Kernel coefficient for ‘rbf’, ‘poly’ and ‘sigmoid’. If gamma is ‘auto’ then 1/n_features will be used instead.

The RBF kernel looks complicated but it's not. It basically just produces 1.0 if a feature vector matches the basis vector, and produces a number that gets closer to 0 as they get more distant. The gamma parameter controls how it declines with distance. The sklearn default gamma parameter is apparently a fixed value based on how many features you have. So, you would expect slightly different results if you scale up and down the feature vectors.

I expect if you change to `kernel=‘linear’` you'll get exactly the same predictions.